# Typecsript and NextJS how to check if "document" exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

NextJS renders part of the code server-side. I can handle that. But I would need to check if cookies are set and here I run into problems. I tried:

`!!document && !!document.cookie`

and

`document !== undefined && !!document.cookie`

Each time I get the same error:

`ReferenceError: document is not defined`

I just want to make this clear, I do not want to render the component exclusively client side. The only thing I want to check is if `document.cookie` is defined or not :)

I am thankful for every answer that would help me solve this problem

---

UPDATE:

I accepted the first answer since it was the correct one. However, I realised my approach was wrong and solved it by explicitly checking the type of document:

`typeof document !== 'undefined' && !!document.cookie`

I guess I did not have enough coffee yet and I missed something pretty obvious.

Comment: Maybe just document?.cookie (or !!document?.cookie if you really want the bool)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next.js uses pre-rendering, so you should wrap any use of `document` in the `useEffect` hook as `document` is not available on the server. That way the particular code gets executed just client-side.

https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-create-react-app#safely-accessing-web-apis

Comment: This was a great answer and I learned something new. However, I found a fundamental flaw in my code, that's why it did not work. I'll post my solution as soon as I can :)